# custom xlabel ticks in Seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have plotted a heatmap which is displayed below. on the xaxis it shows time of the day and y axis shows date. I want to show xaxis at every hour instead of the random xlabels it displays here.[image]

I tried following code but the resulting heatmap overrites all xlabels together:

```
t = pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', end='23:59:59', freq='60T').time
df = pd.DataFrame(index=t)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['index'] = df['index'].astype('str')
sns_hm = sns.heatmap(data=mat, cbar=True, lw=0,cmap=colormap,xticklabels=df['index'])
```

[image]

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: but that is where my problem comes. The original dataframe has nearly 86400 values as it is every second for each day. I just want to display labels for every hour which will come to 24 values per day. How do I do it?

Comment: Note that the heatmaps ticks are always categorical, internally numbered 0,1,2,.... If you need something else, there is matplotlib's `imshow` or `pcolor`.

Comment: @GreyMurav I have to preserve the data frame and cant mess with it. that is why I went to this approach. Isnt there a way I could use this approach with changes?

Comment: @GreyMurav also, i tried through your way. The whole issue with me using this alternative approach was because having 18k points, its taking too much time for generating the plot. That is why I reduced the number of ticks from 18k to 24. but if I create a new column with similar length, it defeats my purpose as it will take similar time.

Comment: How did you create your original plot? How is `mat` structured? Is there one entry every second? Is `mat` a dataframe? Could you create some artificial test data to make this reproducible?

Comment: I figured it out. Wil post a soln soon

Answer (score 2):

The following code supposes `mat` is a dataframe with columns for some timestamps for each of a number of days. Each of the days, the same timestamps need to appear again.

After drawing the heatmap, the left and right limits of the x-axis are retrieved. Supposing these go from 0 to 24 hour, the range can be subdivided into 25 positions, one for each of the hours.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, to_hex

# first, create some test data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["date"] = pd.date_range('20220304', periods=19000, freq=DateOffset(seconds=54))
df["val"] = (((np.random.rand(len(df)) ** 100).cumsum() / 2).astype(int) % 2) * 100
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

mat = df.pivot(index='day', columns='time', values='val')

colors = list(plt.cm.Greens(np.linspace(0.2, 0.9, 10)))
ax = sns.heatmap(mat, cmap=colors, cbar_kws={'ticks': range(0, 101, 10)})
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
tick_pos = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 25)
tick_labels = [f'{h:02d}:00:00' for h in range(len(tick_pos))]
ax.set_xticks(tick_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels, rotation=90)
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The left plot shows the default tick labels, the right plot the customized labels.

[image: sns.heatmap, setting xtick labels per hour]

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?